# How to start new activity after login success in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to start new activity after login success. I don't know the code for starting activity from one to another and how to do it in this code below, i have code for that thing is here, in these it is code for background workers.java and we have two panel :

```
package com.example.androidphp2016;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url1="http://adminlogin.php";
        String login_url2="http://studentlogin.php";
        if(type.equals("login1")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url1);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(type.equals("login2")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url2);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you reached so far ( the code you posted ) then it should be a fairly simple job.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
if (result.equal("something")){
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,newactivity.class);
       startActivity(intent)
}
that is what i'm trying to do

Comment: Why not post a question only about this small piece of code? `onPostExecute(String result) { alertDialog.setMessage(result); alertDialog.show(); if (result.equal("something")){ Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,newactivity.class); startActivity(intent) } ` 
Maybe it would get more answers because shorter code is easier to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding this code into OnPostExecute, and then I declared two activities in the Manifest.xml. thank you for helping me.

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if(result.equals("Admin login success")){

         Intent intent = new Intent(context, adminpanel.class);
         context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(result.equals("Student Login Success")){

     Intent intent = new Intent(context, studentpanel.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
   }
    else
    {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your method onPostExecute check if the result is correct i.e. login is successful if yes then add code:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("caller", "LoginActivity");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
```

I would also suggest you to dismiss your alertDialog using:   `alertDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: I tried the following code, but it gives me an error after login success
"unforanlty androidphp2016 has stopped"
however this error message wont appear the login failed.

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
        if(result.equals("Admin login success")){
         alertDialog.dismiss();
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, adminpanel.class);
             context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(result.equals("Student Login Success")){
         alertDialog.dismiss();
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, studentpanel.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
       }
    }'

Comment: can you try this by completely removing the alertdialog ?

Comment: what is the exact error? please provide the details, maybe the line at which you are getting the error or any other information.

Comment: at the logcat at com.android.internal.os.zygoteinit.main(zygoteinit.java:553)
 at dalvik.system.nativestarter.main(native method)

Comment: please check in you "Android Monitor" there will be a line maybe blue in colour and will direct you to the exact line in code where the error is occurring. please provide that.

Comment: 07-13 14:56:22.097: W/dalvikvm(973): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)

Answer (score -1):

Ok , so for opening new activity you must use these code with proper format according to your code ,

```
Intent i = new Intent(FromfirstActivity.this, TosecondActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

It will definatly help, thanks